# Understanding an example of window function

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I was running a code script to get the following result. The code is shown below. I don't understand why I got the `xyz1` column as shown in the image. For example, why the first row of `xyz1` is `0`. According to the windows function, its corresponding group should be the first two rows, but why `F.count(F.col("xyz")).over(w)` get `0` here.

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('SparkByExamples.com').getOrCreate()
list=([1,5,4],
    [1,5,None],
    [1,5,1],
    [1,5,4],
    [2,5,1],
    [2,5,2],
    [2,5,None],
    [2,5,None],
     [2,5,4])
df=spark.createDataFrame(list,['I_id','p_id','xyz'])
w= Window().partitionBy("I_id","p_id").orderBy(F.col("xyz"))
df.withColumn("xyz1",F.count(F.col("xyz")).over(w)).show()
```

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `count` only counts non-null items, and that the grouping is only defined by the `partitionBy` clause, but not the `orderBy` clause.

When you specify an ordering column, the default window range is (according to the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Window))

```
(rangeFrame, unboundedPreceding, currentRow)
```

So your window defintion is actually

```
w = (Window().partitionBy("I_id","p_id")
             .orderBy(F.col("xyz"))
             .rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
    )
```

And so the window only includes the rows from `xyz = -infinity` to the value of `xyz` in the current row. That's why the first row has a count of zero because it counts non-null items from `xyz = -infinity` to `xyz = null`, i.e. the first two rows of the dataframe.

For the row where `xyz = 2`, the count includes non-null items from `xyz = -infinity` to `xyz = 2`, i.e. the first four rows. That's why you got a count of 2, because the non-null items are 1 and 2.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, for the eighth row in this table (1,5, 4, 3), it seems to me that xyz1 column value for this row should be 2 instead of 3, as it only has one single non-null value row before it.

Comment: The window is inclusive of the values up to the current row. In that case, all rows where xyz <= 3 will be included, so you got a count of 3 rows.